# Prevent cups from automatically adding a local usb printer

Tags: cups

I've disabled remote printer detection and auto profile creation by stopping/disabling cups-browsed service but Ubuntu still auto creates a new printer profile when the same USB printer is moved to another USB port or a new USB printer plugged in. I want to prevent Ubuntu/cups from auto creating printer profiles with default settings/drivers as the default profile doesn't work and I believe it sets this new profile as the default.

Ubuntu 20.04/22.04